# Weird symbol during preview

Tags: dreamweaver, preview, symbols

The problem:
I have a div where I will have a list of selections for users to choose. In this div, i have  
 to separate the selections. Please refer to this link for image https://i.stack.imgur.com/17DY1.jpg.

the code is here:

```
<div id="personal" class="personal"> Personal Details </div>
<div id="menu" class="menu"> Permit </div>
<div id="menulist" class="menulist"> -Apply <br />
    -Renew
    -Track <br />
    -Progress <br />
    -Information </div>
<div class="menu2" id="menu2">Records</div>
<div class="menulist2" id="menulist2">-Permits<br />
    -Training<br />
    -Training Schedule<br />
    -Accidents &amp;  <br />
    &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;Convictions</div>
    </div>
```

And the code for CSS is here:

```
.personal
{
 position:absolute;
 color:#fff;
 top:210px;
 left:20px;
 font-size:20px;
 font-family:'TrajanProBold';
 width:20%;
}

.menu
{
 position:absolute;
 color:#fff;
 top:255px;
 left:20px;
 font-size:30px;
 font-family:'TrajanProBold';
 width:289px;
}

.menulist
{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
top:295px;
left:60px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: 'TrajanProRegular';
width:23%;
}

.menu2
{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
top:401px;
left:20px;
font-size:30px;
font-family:'TrajanProBold';
width:285px;
}

.menulist2
{
position:absolute;
color:#fff;
top:441px;
left:60px;
font-size:20px;
font-family: 'TrajanProRegular';
width:23%;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator to generate font, If error still persist, most likely its due to the font file that is corrupted. After changing the font file, the matter is solved.

Answer (score 0):

It might be a character encoding issue.  Try opening your source code in NotePad++, switch the encoding to UTF-8, and then repost.

Comment: is it this line??

        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />

I think all my file consist of this line...by any chance can it be the due to the XHTML 1.0 Transitional?? i think i set it to strict

Comment: That's setting the content type of the page.  You might have copied/pasted some text in that is causing the odd character.  Trying selecting all text, copy to NotePad++, convert to UTF-8 without BOM (that's the key part - the "without BOM"), and then copy/paste back in your code editor. You should be good.